# File To Array with Text Keys in PHP?

Tags: php

i have been trying to get this to work for a while. I have a File using this format:

```
Value : 1212121212
Value 2 : 1212121212
Value 3 :  1212121212
```

I need to get each value and plus them into a array in this format.

```
array {

"Value" => "1212121212"
"Value 2" => "1212121212"
"Value 3" => "1212121212"
}
```

Where i can get the value like so: `echo $Array[0]['Value'];`

How would i go about doing that? Thanks. Also:

I am a beginner in PHP, so if you could add some documentation with your answer, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: + trim to remove whitespaces

Comment: But how would i get the value on each side? and save it to an array?

Comment: I don't understand the first dimension in your array. Where does the dimension depicted by index value of `0` come from?  In other words, why would you not simply access as `$array['Value']`, `$array['Value 2']`, etc. in the end state?

Comment: Oh, your correct. Sorry, i made a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find all explanations in the comments.

```
// this line reads the file into an array, where each element represents a line
$lines = file('path/file');

// initiate a blank array
$result = array();

// run through all lines
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // explode each line into a new array containing the key and the value
    $temp = explode(' : ', $line);
    // in the result array set the key and the value accordingly
    $result[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
}

// will print the value of 'Value'
print $result['Value'];
```

Here are some links for all the stuff used in this example:

[file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) /
[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) /
[foreach](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php) /
[arrays](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Ah, thanks sooo much. Could you link me with some Documentation? Also, why is there votes to close? I am new, and asked a good question.

Comment: @EliteGamer I've added the necessary links to the PHP documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
$data = array();

// file() returns an array with all lines of the file.
// iterate over them:
foreach(file('your.file') as $line) {
    // split the line by a colon
    $record = explode(':', $line);
    // add the new index to $data
    $data [trim($record[0])] = trim($record[1]);
}

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: How would i get a specific Value?

Comment: like this: `echo $data['Value'];`

Comment: Thanks so much. I appreciate both answers, but i will have to give the answer to insertusernamehere, since he posted it first, and gave a reason and explanation .Thanks!